# Перегрузка методов по параметрам

Tags: java

Почему можно написать так

```
class A {
    public int foo(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    public int foo(double l) {
        int z = abs(2);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

но нельзя так

```
class A {
    public void foo(int i) {}

    public void foo(double l) {
        int z = abs(2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А почему вы решили, что нельзя? И то, и другое - валидные примеры.

UPD: Всё прекрасно собирается, как и ожидалось.

Comment: Больше не буду доверять real time компиляции в eclipse :).

Comment: Clean+Build вам в помощь :)

Comment: "Больше не буду доверять real time компиляции" 
^^ бывает так что у вас в строке "х" была ошибка вы написали другой код в этой строке, но пока не нажали сохранить эклипс все еще будет показывать что она есть